# return statement followed by initializer list

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list

As I was reading a tour of C++ (3rd edition) I came across the following examples using the `complex` class (section 4.2).

Within the complex class definition:

```
complex& operator+=(complex z)
{
    re += z.re;
    im += z.im;
    return *this;
}
```

defined separately from class definition:

```
complex operator+(complex a, complex b)
{
    return a += b;
}

complex operator-(complex a)
{
    return { -a.real(), -a.imag() };
} // unary -
```

1. Can someone help me make sense of why in the `operator+` implementation, the author makes a call to `operator+=`, which changes the value of the complex number object that is making the call? If I were to evaluate the express `a+b`, would I expect the value a to be altered?
2. Also, for the case of `operator-`, I am confused about the statement:

   ```
   return { -a.real(), -a.imag() };
   ```

Is the author using an initializer list after the returns statement? If so, can it be done without specifying the name of the object it is initializing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to ask one question by question.

Comment: *"which changes the value of the complex number object that is making the call"* -- But it doesn't, because it's used on a copy. (`a` is accepted by value, *NOT* by reference!)

Comment: *"If so, can it be done without specifying the name of the object it is initializing?"* Yes, because the type of the object to be initialized is known from the declared return type of the function `operator-`.

Comment: There is one `operator+` defined as member function in the code you show. Including the `this` object, that makes three operands, which is impossible since `operator+` only occurs as unary or binary operator. Is that perhaps missing a `friend`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I expect not all are actually "within the class definition" but rather just in the same header file. The second two operators make perfect sense as free functions. I suspect some copy-paste tomfoolery is to blame.

Comment: Then the code is missing an `inline` in order to be usable. Anyhow, my point was that the representation of the code that causes issues here is false or incomplete, which makes any reasoning guesswork. I also didn't intend this as reply to your comment, @cdhowie, but rather aimed at mlikj2006, just in case that was somehow unclear.

Comment: apologies, i realized that only the definition of operator += resides inside the class definition. The other 2 functions are defined separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator+` is delegating to `operator+=` to avoid having to maintain two function definitions. The argument to `operator+` is not being modified because the operator makes local copies of the arguments by accepting them by value, instead of by reference. So the argument remains unmodified in the context of the caller.

---

The following statement

```
return { -a.real(), -a.imag() };
```

is using *copy-list-initialization* from a *braced-init-list* to construct a `complex` object using the constructor that takes real and imaginary value. This is a C++11 addition, and works because the `std::complex` constructor in question is not `explicit`.

How this works is explained in *[dcl.init.list]/3* and *[over.match.list]/1*. Any constructors of `std::complex` that take an `std::initializer_list<T>` argument, would be considered first. If no such constructor exists (which is the case with `std::complex`), or if the constructor is not viable for the types of the arguments in the *braced-init-list*, other constructors of `std::complex` will be enumerated, and the best match selected via overload resolution.

Comment: As a side note: That `operator+` implementation would be an excellent place for someone to simply put a comment `// note: a is a copy of the first argument, so it is safe to mutate it` or something similar.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'd expect that to be self-evident to any reasonably competent C++ developer.

Comment: @cdhowie: then you are lucky enough to work with a remarkably large number of competent C++ developers =)  To quote Guido van Rossum, "Code is written one, but read many times."  It is considerate to help the reader along.  It is not often that a developer has to dig into their memory to remember that `+=` even returns a value, much less the semantics of it.  Consider the developer who looks at such a class and thinks "why don't we use `const complex&` to save a copy?"  My sympathy for the developer that ever has to wonder, "how did this ever work in the first place?"

Comment: One comment may be all they need to straighten themselves out, and it isn't a very costly act to put it in.  It could sit there for a decade before becoming useful once.  It isn't like this is Javascript, where we actually care about byte-count of the source code =)

Comment: I would also go for a two line solution: `a += b; return a;`, which also makes it much clearer what is going on, but does so with code rather than comments.

Comment: I actually like `a += b; return a;` better than `return a += b;`, but for a completely different reason: the first version allows moving from `a`. Obviously for `complex` this doesn't do anything, but with more complex types it can be significant.